# Python (File Path Selecting)

Tags: python, input, filepath

OS : **Windows**

Language : **Python**

**Code**

```
location=input("Enter The File Path: ")
```

**Output**

```
Enter The File Path: C:\\\New
```

So I need to Enter the file path without typing two \ in Windows any suggestions???

Comment: What makes you think that two backslashes would be needed here? That's only required for Windows file paths that are contained directly in your code as string literals (and there are other options even there).

Comment: Ok. My code is running fine Now. Just a little bit of confusion